# How can I prevent Mathematica from evaluating or "simplifying" an expression?

Tags: expression-manipulation, hold

Simple example:

```
k = 5;
list = {};
For[i = 1, i <= k - 2,
 AppendTo[list, 1/(1 + Cos[i Pi/k])];
 i = i + 2];
Print[list];

{1/(1+1/4 (1+Sqrt[5])),1/(1+1/4 (1-Sqrt[5]))}
```

I want the expression to be kept and printed as:

```
{1/(1 + Cos[Pi/5]), 1/(1 + Cos[3 Pi/5])}
```

I have tried `Hold` and its several versions, but nothing seems to do the trick.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3):

```
k = 5;
list = {};
For[i = 1, i <= k - 2, 
  With[{i = i, k = k}, 
   AppendTo[list, HoldForm[1/(1 + Cos[(i \[Pi])/k])]]];
  i = i + 2];
Print[list];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Perhaps `Table[With[{i = i, k = k}, HoldForm[1/(1 + Cos[i Pi /k])]], {i, 1, 
  k - 2, 2}]` is more Mathemaica-ish

Comment: @belisarius I know, but that's not what the OP wanted.

Comment: Sjoerd: I know you know :). I was "talking"  to the OP. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 3):

As stated `HoldForm` is your friend here.  Also see `Defer` if you intend to reuse the output.

Equivalent methods:

```
Table[With[{i = i, k = k}, HoldForm[1/(1 + Cos[i Pi/k])]], {i, 1, k - 2, 2}]

Table[{i, k} /. {i_, k_} :> HoldForm[1/(1 + Cos[i Pi/k])], {i, 1, k - 2, 2}]

Table[HoldForm[1/(1 + Cos[# Pi/#2])] &[i, k], {i, 1, k - 2, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]