# Stopping Mathematica from reordering expressions

Tags: output-formatting, polynomials, expression-manipulation

I want *Mathemtica* to stop manipulating my polynomials! I mean, I want the output of

```
Print[3 x + 5 + x^2]
```

to be just $3x+5+x^2$, not $5+3x+x^2$ as *Mathematica* returns.

How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe wrapping it in `Defer[]` will do what you want? (I guess it will depend on how you want to use the expression.)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau As I said below eldo's answer, if we have parameters, there will be another problem: commands a=-3;
Print[Defer[ax-5+x^2]] yield $ax-5+x^2$, not $-3x-5+x^2$.

Comment: @Behzad You can't both *have* and *not have* evaluation ...  What is your use case for this exactly?  Understand that will help come up with a solution.  Generally, consider everything you enter into Mathematica as program code, not a mathematical expression. The way Mathematica works implies that this transformation *will* take place and it's not a good idea to try to change that. What I suggest instead is to have two steps: 1) one processing step where you manipulate symbolic expressions, letting Mathematica work the way it does 2) and a formatting step where you print them to specification.

Comment: Specifically for your example, `With[{a=3}, Print@HoldForm[a x - 5 + x^2]]` does work, but I don't know if it's general enough for your use case.

Comment: Related: [9570](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9570), [20714](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20714)

Comment: Also related: [(6358)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6358),
[(7880)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7880),
[(15744)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15744),
[(21519)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21519),
[(22431)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22431),
[(30216)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30216),
[(31974)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31974), [(40165)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40165/121), [(46535)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46535)

Comment: After looking at about a dozen related questions I picked one that I think is closest to what you want.  I have marked this question as a duplicate of that question.  Please review it, and its answers, and tell me if your problem is solved therein.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Please practice your gentle ministry to close down questions more hesitantly. The question you picked (after having reviewed many other archeological sites) is a question of which you were the prime respondent.

Comment: @eldo Yes, it is.  Unfortunately I don't have a good memory, and actually writing in answer is one of the few things I seems to (sometimes) remember, so I am biased toward Questions that I have answered.  If you have another Question in mind that would be a better fit please let me know!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I don't have another question in mind, but I feel that THIS question has an elegant and new answer with Kuba's comment. Therefore, it shouldn't be disqualified in one way or the other. Also, the `Print`- statement complicates things here.

Comment: @eldo, Kuba's comment does not handle the OP's comment re `a x - 5 + x^2`.

Comment: @I added another Question to my related list that is perhaps closer still. (Last in line.)  I'll leave this as is until Behzad clarifies his full intent, unless someone has an Answer he wishes to post in which case I shall reopen.

Answer (score 7):

Will

```
a = -3; Print[Defer[\[FormalA] x + 5 + x^2] /. \[FormalA] -> a]
```

> -3 x + 5 + x^2

work for you?

Comment: it may not work for `1` or `0`. but don't know what's OP need.

Answer (score 4):

What about

```
Print[HoldForm[3 x + 5 + x^2]]
```

?

Comment: Well, if we have parameters, there will be another problem: commands a=-3;
Print[HoldForm[ax-5+x^2]] yield $ax-5+x^2$, not $-3x-5+x^2$.

Comment: @Behzad There will always be a problem unless you post full context :) this answer fits the question. You can use `With` to inject in held expressions but I suppose it may still be a problem with sign marks. `With[{a = -3}, HoldForm[a x - 5 + x^2]]`

Comment: @Kuba Interesting question though, because `fun = 3 x + 5 + x^2`; and then `Print[HoldForm@fun]` doesn't work.

Comment: @eldo With `Set` it is already lost so even if you inject it it will be formated :) but with `SetDelayed` you can do: `ClearAll[fun]; fun := 3 x + 5 + x^2;` and then `HoldForm[fun] /. OwnValues@fun`

Comment: @kuba Brilliant ! If OP wants this, he could even append a `// Print` after `/. OwnValues@fun`.